# как удалить refind?

Tags: linux, macos

Установил через скрипт refind boot manager, а как теперь вернуть все на свои места?

Comment: **вернуть** — скорее всего, никак: вместо одного загрузчика можно лишь установить другой.

Comment: а можно в принципе снести все-все-все и вернуть к заводским настройкам? Если да, то как?

Comment: видимо, я чего-то недопонимаю. что значит «вернуть к заводским настройкам»? ведь «с завода» накопитель информации выходит чистым (ну, за исключением какой-то служебной разметки). заполните накопитель «нулями» — вот и получите «заводскую настройку».

Comment: ладно, а если настройку которая была у меня при выходе из магазина?

Comment: я, видимо, совсем вас не понимаю. если в магазине вам что-то записали на носитель информации, а сейчас вы хотите это неизвестно что вновь получить на том же носителе, то самое логичное — уточнить в магазине, что же они вам туда записывали.

Comment: а если я отформатирую жесткий диск и установлю yosetime, все вернется на круги своя?

Comment: *yosetime* — может быть, вы имели в виду *yosemite* (это, кажется, кодовое название одной из версий дистрибутива операционной системы *mas/osx*)? ну, да, в конце установки дистрибутива, по идее, должен быть установлен и один из идущих в комплекте с дистрибутивом загрузчиков. ввиду того, что вы не знаете, какой загрузчик был установлен на вашей машине в магазине, с некоторой долей вероятности это может окажеться именно **он**.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: там всегда есть скрытый раздел для восстановления, с которого можно накатить систему заново в случае какого-нибудь былинного провала.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, «там» — это где?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: на жестких дисках систем с предустановленной OS X.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, автор об этом не пишет. если бы написал — я б и не влезал в дискуссию.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: ну вот я за него и уточнил )

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27377/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: Извините, только увидел про чат, отписался там, надеюсь что знатоки помогут решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

введите команду в терминале: sudo apt remove refind

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ошибка «sudo: apt: command not found»